# Is there a node.js documentation URl that is Webstorm compatbile?

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I would like to have WebStorm resolve node.js functions (as I am a green square addict!)

Does anyone know how I can make this happen?

D

Comment: Write the documentation yourself then share it with us, please :)

Comment: I just put up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are [working](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-3451) on it.

Answer (score 0):

Its now implemented:

1. First you have to click the NodeJS icon

   [image: NodeJS Icon]
2. Then fill out the details (try `which node` to find the interpreter binary), and I just allowed webstorm to download the source.

   [image: Node.js setup]

HTH

Comment: Did that make documentation available for Node.JS?